# Monitoring leaked jdbc hibernate connections via web in tomcat

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, jdbc, resource-leak

I remember that ~5 years ago I was working on a project that had some url like

http://myhost.com/connections

that showed stacktraces of open connections, so I could easily find out leaks. How can I setup such url now in my tomcat app that uses hibernate? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look at [this project](https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/Commons-DBCP-monitoring) if you are using DBCP. It does not provide stack traces but you can always obtain them via `Thread.getAllStackTraces()` and filtering against state, name, etc.